# What is the output printed by following program? How to evaluate the if condition expression?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

What will be the output for the code snippet given below?

```
int main()
{
    if(0<7<5)
        printf("I am printed");
    else
        printf("I am not printed");
}
```

1. I am printed
2. I am not printed
3. Compiler error
4. None

Comment: Try it, then you will get the output.

Comment: Note that an `if` statement is _not_ a loop statement.

Answer (score 6):

The output will be `"I am printed"` - reason being the `<` (less than operator) is left associative. As a result this will be

```
(0<7)<5
```

And as it is true - it will evaluate to 1. So the check will be `1<5`, which is again true, giving you the desired result.

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note107) itself

> The expression `a<b<c` is not interpreted as in ordinary mathematics. As
>   the syntax indicates, it means `(a<b)<c`; in other words, if `a` is less
>   than `b`, compare `1` to `c`; otherwise, compare `0` to `c`.

Answer (score 2):

The "I am printed" will be printed in this function.

```
(0<7<5)  =>  (0<7)<5  =>  1<5  => true.
```